# Architecture Java EE ? many ressources : database, xml 

Tags: java, architecture, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb

I have a Java application and now I want to make it an web app.
Now I think about how to make the architecture of this app.

In fact, I have many resources, matlab, exe files and XML files and a MySQL database.
so we will have a 3-tier architecture.

Client: Browser
Treatment: Java EE server (maybe Servlet and EJB container)
Data: matlab, exe files and XML files and a MySQL database

So, how can I create this application without having a problem even if we have several clients connected which sends many queries at the same time?

Knowing that the processing is calling an EXE and reading and writing XML files, and execute MATLAB.

More details

INPUT -RESSOURCE-> OUTPUT

image(query) -exe-> XML

XML -JDOM-> Java Objects (List)

Java Objects -JDOM-> n XML files

n XML files -JDOM-> txt files

txt files -matlab-> txt files

txt files -MYSQL-> java objects (List)

txt files --> Images (results)

Comment: Will the exe fail if it's invoked concurrently? So if you have multiple users running that exe as a result of web requests will the exe be able to handle it? Does the exe have constraints on local directory structure?

Comment: I dont know, I have not tested it

Comment: okay - will it matter if the exe is kicked off asynchronously? Do you need to show the data back from the exe to the web client or does the exe just need to kick off some process for some reason?

Comment: exe file will just do some process (generate a xml file)

Comment: You could add requests to a queue and do batch processing if concurrent EXEs are a problem and if your users can wait for the processing to complete.

Comment: Jeff you're absolutely right , user have to wait 40 sec (launch of exe and matlab...) to have the result, so how can we make a queue and batch processing with J2EE platform? any framwork do that easily ?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty broad question. So I will keep my answer at a high level and we can dig deeper as you have more questions.

Initially this is how I would structure the application.

1. Pick a MVC framework. I would pick [JSF2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html) but anything else is fine too. Your view and controller layer will be defined here.
2. Create 3 DAO classes at bare minimum - one for reading data from XML, one for reading data from mySql, and one for reading text files. To parse XML files you can use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) and ofcourse SQLs to get data from the database.
3. Create a [MDB](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/EJBConcepts5.html) to asynchronously kick off the EXE process via [JMS](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/).
4. Package the application as an EAR file.

**Tools you can use:**

1. Eclipse for IDE
2. JBoss-AS (or any other container that you have access to)
3. Some sort of build/packaging tool (ANT, Maven, etc)

I am not familiar with image manipulation so I can't comment on that part. However, I think you need to break down your design into various components first. That's why I started listing the ones that I could think of without enough details. So image query will be one of the components. Try to create a black box diagram of the system with each major component in & out. After that start developing each of them and then I bet a lot more folks here can help you with more specific questions. Does this make sense?

Comment: Can you see again my question please, I added some details !!

Comment: This is the problem, image manipulation is different than other things
,so do you have any other comment? because there are a lot of I/O of txt and XML files and calling matlab ...

Comment: Yes for text files you will need to create file parsers (read lines from a file, parse them using some token) and for XML files as I mentioned above you can use XPath.

Comment: For information, I have already created the application with SWING (desktop application) and now I wanna make it web !!  but I dont know if I have to take a look to JSP/Servlet, EJB or some frameworks.

Comment: JSPs are your pure view layer where you show the data on a browser. MDB (as I mentioned above message driven beans) would be a kind of EJB. You can start looking for JSF tutorials on google. I am not trying to be vague but I don't know what information I can provide to help you without making it sound like a tutorial. :-)

Comment: Also not for the sake of throwing buzz words out there, [http://www.springsource.org/ Spring] may be a good alternative to EJBs for you.